# iOS Map Annotation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, annotations, mkmapview

I have a map view with several annotations on it and a search bar.  Everything works fine in iOS 6 but there is an issue in iOS 7.  In iOS 7 when I select a pin, the title pops up and I can tap the info button to go to a detail view for that location.  The problem is when I search on iOS 7, the annotation that is the result of the search comes up with a black area around the annotation and I can't tap the info button.

Here is selecting a pin without searching:

[image]

And here it is after searching for one:

[image]

Here is my code for what happens when you search:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    id<MKAnnotation> ann;
    BOOL annotationFound = NO;
    // NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    // NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    for (int i = 0; i < [marketLocations count]; i++)
    {
        for (ann in marketLocations)
        {
            NSString *annTitle = ann.title;
            NSString *annSubtitle = ann.subtitle;
            NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];
            NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D annCoord;
            annCoord.latitude = ann.coordinate.latitude;
            annCoord.longitude = ann.coordinate.longitude;

            // if ([ann.title isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annCoord, 5000, 5000);
                [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
                annotationFound = YES;
            }
            // else if ([ann.subtitle isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            else if (subtitleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annCoord, 5000, 5000);
                [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
                annotationFound = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    if (annotationFound == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Matches Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [av show];
    }

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two odd things about the search code shown and I believe both of them are helping cause the strange display issue:

1. The outer `for` loop goes through the `marketLocations` array and the inner `for` loop ***also*** goes through the `marketLocations` array.

   This nesting doesn't seem necessary and causes the search to execute more iterations than you need.

   If there are say 100 annotations, the search will execute 100 x 100 iterations (10,000) instead of just 100 (since there are no `break`s in the loops).  Perhaps you may be noticing a slight delay in the search when there are more than just a few annotations.

   It looks like you only need a single `for` loop.
2. When a "matching" annotation is found, the code calls `setRegion` and `selectAnnotation` (both of which involve updates to the display) and then ***continues*** with the search loop.

   Continuing to search for more matching annotations after you've already called `selectAnnotation` on one doesn't make sense because the map view only allows a single annotation to be "selected" (showing a callout) at a time anyway.

   You should either `break` the loop once a matching annotation is found or keep track of the "best matching annotation" and call `setRegion` and `selectAnnotation` *after* the search loop.

I believe the very tight looping for hundreds (possibly thousands) of iterations combined with the multiple, rapid calls to `setRegion` and `selectAnnotation` are causing this display issue.  I was able to replicate it with 100 annotations.

Why it only appears in iOS 7 is something I cannot answer but I doubt iOS 6 is happy about it either (and just not showing it).

So my suggestions are:

1. Use a single `for` loop and,
2. Assuming you want to stop at the first "match", do `break` to stop the loop immediately after calling `selectAnnotation`.

The code might look something like this:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    id<MKAnnotation> ann;
    BOOL annotationFound = NO;

    // SINGLE for-loop...
    for (ann in marketLocations)
    {
        NSString *annTitle = ann.title;
        NSString *annSubtitle = ann.subtitle;
        NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];
        NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annCoord;
        annCoord.latitude = ann.coordinate.latitude;
        annCoord.longitude = ann.coordinate.longitude;

        if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annCoord, 5000, 5000);
            [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            annotationFound = YES;
            break;  // <-- STOP searching, exit the loop
        }
        else if (subtitleRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annCoord, 5000, 5000);
            [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            annotationFound = YES;
            break;  // <-- STOP searching, exit the loop
        }
    }

    if (annotationFound == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Matches Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [av show];
    }

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is only occurring when the annotation result is the last one it finds with a match and is therefore the one that gets shown.  If I add the breaks in there the problem doesn't show up.  The problem with that though is my search results, while technically correct, aren't what I want.  For example, with the break in there if I search haney, I get the annotation for chaney because it gets to it first.

Comment: Right, so you have to first loop through all annotations to find the "best match" and then call selectAnnotation on it after the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would find the best match though.

Comment: Your existing logic (without the `break`) was basically using the _last_ match as the one to select (even if that last one was "chaney" and you were searching for "haney").  How you choose the "best" match is up to you but the general idea is this (given in further comments):

Comment: 1) Before the loop, declare another annotation variable called `bestAnn` and set it to `nil`.  2) In the loop, when you find a "match", if `bestAnn` is `nil` then set `bestAnn` to the new match otherwise compare the new match to `bestAnn` and if the new match is "better" than `bestAnn` set `bestAnn` equal to the new match and _continue_ with the loop.  3) _After_ the loop, if `bestAnn` is nil, show your alert view otherwise, call `setRegion` using `bestAnn.coordinate` and `selectAnnotation` using `bestAnn`.  You won't need the `annotationFound` variable.

Comment: The main point of the answer is to not call `setRegion` and `selectAnnotation` repeatedly _every_ time you find a match as this is causing the display issue.  Call `setRegion` and `selectAnnotation` once _after_ you've decided which annotation to select.

Comment: I get how to implement it for the most part.  I'm just not sure how I go about determining if a match is better than the previous one.

Comment: The question of how to determine the "best" match is separate from and unrelated to the display issue.  As I said, your original code was using the approach that the "last" match is the "best" match.  If that works for you, it's fine.  If not, what makes one match "better" than another is something that needs to be decided _outside_ of code (it's a "business" decision).  Once you decide in plain English what is a "better" match, _then_ try to code it.

Comment: One coding approach is to assign a "weight" or "score" to a match (the closer the match is to the "ideal", the higher its score).  Then you simply choose the match with the highest score (will have to decide what to do if multiple matches have the same score -- maybe based on distance from user).  The question then is what is "ideal" for your app and how to write the weight/score calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a very simple fix.  Instead of

`NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

I've changed it to

`NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText];`

And set

```
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```